# Hide Iteration Area's WIs from the rest of a Project

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps Services:

- I need to hide all WIs belonging to one of the teams (= their Iteration Path) from the rest of the project.
- Yet the team will need to see everyone else's WIs in this project

What is a proper way to achieve that?

- set 'Deny' on 'View work items in this node' for all 'Contributors' and 'Readers'? But if my team is in 'Contributors' (so they can see all the other WIs) their access will also be denied (by inheritance), even if i add them explicitly.

[Area Path 'Security' settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UALIB.png)

I hoped to google a ready solution for such a common request, but have not found one yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> But if my team is in 'Contributors' (so they can see all the other WIs) their access will also be denied (by inheritance), even if i add them explicitly.

This is actually an expected behavior which you can refer to [Permission settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page%2Ccurrent-page#permission-settings), it says `For most groups and almost all permissions, Deny overrides Allow.`, this means when one of the team members is denied from `View work items in this node` in one group(such as his team) and allowed in another group(such as Contributors), he can't see the specific team's work items since the `Deny overrides Allow`.

It's also simple to understand logically, user A will be allowed to see another team's work items when his team is denied from?

My opinion is that you should move the user A to another team which could see the work items in the specific team.

Comment: Is it clear now why you met the problem? As i said, it's a default behavior and you can not prevent, move to another team should be a better choice. If this helps, you can [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or you can keep asking if it's still confusing.